# Django filter by query result

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In my fixturesquery below you can see I am filtering by the results of the teamsquery, and it works, but only for the first result of the teamsquery. So it only outputs the fixtures for the first userteam__userID=request.user

```
    teamsquery = Team.objects.filter(userteams__userID=request.user)
    fixturesquery = Fixtures.objects.filter(Q(hometeamID=teamsquery) | 
                    Q(awayteamID=teamsquery))
```

How do i fix it so it outputs the fixtures for all the results of teamsquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your user can have multiplte teams, right?
If so, you can use:

`teamsquery = Team.objects.filter(userteams__userID=request.user)
fixturesquery = Fixtures.objects.filter(Q(hometeamID__in=teamsquery)|Q(awayteamID__in=teamsquery))`